# How to replace space-filled cells in pandas when input file is space-delimited?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use pandas read_csv to make a df of a file that is space delimited. The problem is that sometimes one of the columns has cells that are simply spaces ('      ') instead of a string. When using this code, I get the error 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

I have used regex (delimiter = r"\s+") to get the code to not have an error, but then it reads the whole blank cell as the delimiter and just skips over that cell instead of marking it as a value, therefore shifting all consequent column values to the left.

```py
import pandas as pd
markets = ['foodsmm']
for market in markets:
    file = market + '.mktxtr.' + pmin
    def format_marketfile(file):

        df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, delimiter = ' ', parse_dates = ['DATE'],
                 names = ['MKT', 'MKT_ID', 'CHILD_MKT', 'STATUS', 'TYPE', 'DATE', 'ACV_UNIV', 'ACV_SMP', 'PROJ_ACV', 'STOREUNIV_ACV', 'STORESMP_CT', 'PROJ_STORECT', 'NADA'])
        df = df.drop(['MKT', 'NADA'], axis=1)
        export_name = file + '.output.csv'
        df.to_csv(export_name, index=False)

    format_marketfile(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `''` before running `read_csv`:

```
df.replace('', '-', inplace=True)
```